# How to precisely define the placement of the labels in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz, draw, circuits

[image: RL series]

I want to have complete control on where to put the labels R1 and L1, the annotation 100 Ohms and the Voltage VL.

1. For example, how to move L1 label a little more to the right, and a little more to the up?
2. How to move the + and the - signs a little closer towards VL? (And I want to colour these signs in red for better emphasization)

   ```
   \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone} 
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \usepackage{circuitikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
   \draw (0,0) 
     to [R, l=$R_1$,a=\SI{100}{\ohm},o-] (3,0)
     to [L, l=$L_1$, v=$V_L$,-o] (6,0)
   ;\end{circuitikz}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Labels are actually nodes themselves.  You can also use \fbox or \raisebox to move the text relative to the node.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114379/circuitikz-0-3-0-label-relative-position/129326?s=2|38.9595#129326

Comment: Try `\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=.8}` for the +/- placement.  Interestingly, larger values are closer together and smaller or negative values are further away..

Comment: Coloring the built in +/- is not an option.  Nor is it easily patched.  I suggest you simply add your own nodes.  Use the `to [L,name=L1]` option (for example) and place nodes relative to (L1).

Comment: Obviously using `\node at (_coord_) {_anything_};` you can put _anything_ at _coord_.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't know how to use \fbox but the \raisebox you suggested worked so that is one problem solved.

Comment: @JohKormylo I really don't know why but I put the `\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=.8}` inside the circuitikz environment and it gives me an error instead. I don't know where to put it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Adding my own nodes at `[L,name=L1]`is something I unfortunately don't know how to do. I still don't know how to manipulate nodes. Could you help me on that one?

Comment: @vipa I still don't know how to manipulate nodes. Could you be more explicit on the suggested solution?

Comment: Since circuitikz IS TikZ, it helps to learn that manual as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bipoles name compass point anchors `se` (for example) instead of `south east`, but otherwise behave the same as any TikZ node.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=.8}
\draw (0,0) 
  to [R, l=$R_1$,a=\SI{100}{\ohm},o-] (3,0)
  to [L, -o, name=L1] (6,0);
\node[above, xshift=2pt, yshift=2pt] at (L1.n) {$L_1$};
\node[below] at (L1.s) {$V_L$};
\node[red,below] at (L1.w) {\scriptsize$+$};
\node[red,below] at (L1.e) {$-$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]